# How to add a geom_text conditioned on a character variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a character variable with four different names (a,b,c,d). I plot their values using the following code:

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(val, name))
```

However, i would like to add a text on the plot that would differentiate within the character variable. For instance, between `a` and `b` i would like to write "group 1" and between `c` and `d` i would like to write "group 2". That way the reader can understand that there are subgroups within the same group. I used `geom_text` previously on a plot that had two numeric variables, but i don't know how to do it when there is one numeric and one character variable.

Here is the plot that i get:

[image]

Here is the plot that i am aiming to do:
[image]

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(name = structure(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), format.stata = "%9s"), 
    val = c(2, 4, 1.5, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You might find a solution in the package `ggh4x` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggh4x/vignettes/PositionGuides.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(name = structure(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), format.stata = "%9s"), 
                     val = c(2, 4, 1.5, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(val, name))+
  geom_point() +
  annotate("text", y = 1.5, x = 1, label = "Group 1", angle = 90, size = 8) +
  annotate("text", y = 3.5, x = 1, label = "Group 2", angle = 90, size = 8) +
  annotate("text", y = 1.5, x = 1.2, label = "}", size = 24) +
  annotate("text", y = 3.5, x = 1.2, label = "}", size = 24)
```

[image: example_1.png]

Or perhaps something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

df <- structure(list(name = structure(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), format.stata = "%9s"), 
                     val = c(2, 4, 1.5, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(name %in% c("a", "b"), "group a + b", "group c + d")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(val, name))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = group,
                        color = group))
```

[image: example_2.png]

Answer (score 2):

here is another approach:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(pBrackets)


df <- structure(list(name = structure(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), format.stata = "%9s"),
               val = c(2, 4, 1.5, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df %<>% mutate(
            letter.val = match( name, letters ),
            group = 1+floor( (letter.val-1) / 2 )
        )

df.a <-  df %>% group_by(group) %>%
    summarize( val = 1.5, name = mean(letter.val) )

ggplot( df, aes(x=val,y=name,group=group) ) +
    geom_point( ) +
    geom_text( data=df.a, aes(label=sprintf("Group %d",group)), angle=90 ) +
    theme_bw()

bracket.x <- 88
grid.brackets(bracket.x, 440,   bracket.x, 489, lwd=2)
grid.brackets(bracket.x, 141,   bracket.x, 196, lwd=2)
```

[image: brackets]

To identify coordinates for grid.brackets, use [grid.locator](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grid/versions/3.6.2/topics/grid.locator) (it is somewhat clunky in use)

Answer (score 1):

@jad there are 2 ways of adding explanatory notes/text to a visualisation:

- geom_text() (or geom_label())
- annotate()

For a start think about geom_text/label() to be data point markings, while annotate() are more general purpose markings.

Generally, one would place a geom_text/label at or next to the data point to "name" it.
However, you can work with the placement, i.e. x, y position, of a geom_text/label() as well.
In the example, I put all labels on x = 3.5 to demonstrate this.
I also inject the label tags in the data frame as a separate column. Note that you could work with setting some of the labels to NA. geom_text/label() has a na.rm parameter; if set to TRUE, you remove the NAs (= do not display them) silently. Alternatively, you could print an empty string "". But that is just tricking the display of the geom.

The - 2nd option - is more for selective markings. `annotate()` allows you to place the annotation again via x and y. Dependent on the context, you can provide multiple annotations as a vector or add (an)other annotation layer(s).
For what you want to get I added a hjust and angle argument. Since we rotate by angle = 90 degrees, we need to displace the label "horizontally".
The displacement (:= alignment to x, y) is needed to find a middle position as your y axis is categorical. In a numerical context, you can calculate the midposition and assign it to the y-value for example. With categorical vars, you would need to trick a bit again. With hjust (or vjust) you can utilise the most straightforward way to achieve the discplacement/alignment.

```
    # add group labels to data frame
    df$label <- c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 1", "Group 2")
    
    ggplot(df)+
      geom_point(aes(val, name)) +

    # use geom_text/label() to place "many" tags typically to data points
    # here we force them to be "fixed" at x = 3.5
      geom_text(aes(x = 3.5, y = name, label = label)) +

    # use annotation as a selective add on
    # you can combine multiple annotations in one call by assigning 
    # vector to position x or y, and label
      annotate(geom = "text", x = 1, y = c("a","c"), label = c("Group 1", "Group 2")
              # to rotate label set angle, hjust for alignment
               , angle = 90, hjust = -0.5
              )
```

[image: use of geom_text() vs annotate()]

Obviously, you could also use colour or shapes to highlight and differentiate the sub-groups. Alternatively - in this example - you may put a "coloured band" under or box around the data points to signal different groupings.

How to add the brackets ... check for the other answers.